# Insert ş on my Word for Mac

Tags: macos, keyboard, ms-office, language

I have to write my essay in Romanian language and I have to put inside the text a lot of **ş** or similar characters.

I managed System Preferences and select Language & Text, "Input Sources" and check "Romanian", "Serbian" and so on.

In Pages I can type all the letters without any problem but this doesn't work in Word for Mac.

Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: What does your keyboard look like and how is it configured? What do you get when you type those keys in Word?

Comment: What version of Word are you using?

Comment: Is it a font issue? Are you using a different font in Word, which perhaps doesn't have the symbol? But - what MacOS, what version of Word.